# Using a named group only for a back reference

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

In this regular expression:

```
/\b([aeiouy])\w{2}\1\w+\b/g
```

The capture group is only used by the back reference `\1`.

Is it possible to declare a named group with only exist for back reference?

The only thing I can do to exclude `([aeiouy])` from the matches is `(?:)`, but in that case I cannot use my back reference anymore.

For example in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
$_ = 'accordion accalmie diacritic ettercap';
say join ' ', /\b(([aeiouy])\w{2})\2(\w+)\b/g;
```

Where I want to display this:

```
acc lmie ett rcap
```

not this:

```
acc a lmie ett e rcap
```

Another solution would involve named group:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
$_ = 'accordion accalmie diacritic ettercap';
print Dumper \%+ while /\b(?<pre>([aeiouy])\w{2})\2(?<post>\w+)\b/g;

$VAR1 = {
          'post' => 'lmie',
          'pre' => 'acc'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'post' => 'rcap',
          'pre' => 'ett'
        };
```

**EDIT**

Another example that might be better than the above one is this case:

```
m/(?<=<(name)>)\w+(?=<\/\1>)/g
```

Where I want to match `foo` and `bar`

```
<item>
   <name>foo</name>
   <id>23</id>
</item>
<item>
   <name>bar</name>
   <id>42</id>
</item>
```

The group `(name)` allow to not repeat myself and here I am using lookaround to properly match `foo` and `bar`. However, this solution is less clean than

```
m/(?<=<name>)\w+(?=<\/name>)/g
```

that will not return any irrelevant capture groups. In my original question I am trying to find a way to refer to a capture group without using it outside the regex.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. It means that the capture group numbers would be different for back-references and the matches array, which would be very confusing.

Comment: I also don't think that there is a way in any regex engine I'm aware of. However, note that you should add a tag naming the regex engine you are using.

Comment: @anubhava It is sometime very useful to match several part of a string to use them outside. To avoid confusion, the internal matches *i.e.* recursion, back-reference, should be eliminated from the output.

Comment: There are ways to discard them from matching array e.g. `unset($matches[1]);` in PHP

Comment: To avoid confusion and have more maintainable code overall, use **named groups**.

Comment: could you post input and desired output? What with something like [that](https://regex101.com/r/cF0gP3/1)? The group is not a part of match, but you can use it as backreference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer to your question but I cannot comment here on Stack Overflow yet.

Why not take `$1` and `$3` directly, avoiding what you don't want (`$2`)?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
$_ = 'accordion accalmie diacritic ettercap';
my @parts;
push @parts, $1, $3 while /\b(([aeiouy])\w{2})\2(\w+)\b/g;
say join ' ', @parts;
# prints "acc lmie ett rcap\n"
```

Comment: In fact I could do what you say. However I am looking for a more generic approach where I don't need to manually consider each `$n` match. I want to consider my regex as a black box that returns only what I need with no garbage information.

Answer (score 1):

It is not direct answer for a question, but I think that this kind of match could be achieved with regex like:

```
(?=\b([aeiouy])\w{2}\1\w+\b)\w{3}|(?<=(?!\A)\G[aeiouy])\w+\b
```

which should match `acc` and `lmie`, as separate matches.